# iPhone 5 view frame changes

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, autoresize, iphone-5

The app I'm currently working on has a huge number of views. Some are webviews and some normal UIViews, with a ton of subviews. Now that the iPhone 5 has come out, how can I *most efficiently* change the frame size of the entire app to support both 4-inch and 3.5 inch devices? I certainly could use a whole bunch of if-else statements and layout several frame sizes for each view, but what's the *best, most efficient* way this could be done?

Comment: the _most efficient way_ depends on how well you managed the `UIView` objects, their `autoresizeMask` property or the frames and sizes...

Answer (score 1):

*Most efficient* way is to use one of the provided layouting mechanisms:

1. **Autoresizing** – Each `UIView` has property `autoresizingMask` and by setting it to one or many values (using `|` operator) you tell the view how to behave when the size of its superview changes. Elementary options:

   - `UIViewAutoresizingFlexible...`

     - `...Width`
     - `...Height`
     - `...LeftMargin`
     - `...RightMargin`
     - `...TopMargin`
     - `...BottomMargin`
2. **Auto Layout** – New in iOS 6, it provides more complex (very complicated) mechanism of relations between view attributes. Basicaly it is a superset of autoresizing and there are some long docs for it. *I don't recommend it to you.*